# is it possible to backup an uploaded program?

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, bootloader

I have a cute robot built on Arduino Uno and Ardumoto, and I am trying to reverse engineer it first, and to add some new sensors afterwards.

I am stuck at how to deal with its program. I don't have the source code but I do not want to loose the program, yet in order to reverse engineer it I must write my own code and see if I can make it work.

Beware, I am a n00b to microcontrolers, and pretty lame to electronics (full of enthusiasm though).

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE! The question here is a duplicate of [this question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/179/is-there-any-way-to-download-a-sketch-from-an-arduino). Although downloading and backing up are slightly different, the other post has answers that fit your criteria. If you feel that they are not duplicates, please edit this post using the edit button to specify what exactly you want. Thanks!